# Problem at opening NASA World Wind. I get a terminal error (java problem)

Tags: command-line, java

The program is zipped and these are the instruccions in README file:

```
2) cd to the World Wind release folder.
3) chmod +x run-demo.bash
4) ./run-demo.bash gov.nasa.worldwindx.examples.ApplicationTemplate
```

I type step 4 and I get this terminal error

```
Running gov.nasa.worldwindx.examples.ApplicationTemplate
./run-demo.bash: línea [line] 16: java: orden no encontrada [command not found]
```

The program use .jnlp files, opened with Oracle Java Web Start, included in Java Runtime Environment. Maybe I don't have it, how I can know it? Searching on my computer I only found two files: JavaWebStartAppletTemplate.jnlp and JavaWebStartTemplate.jnlp. I tried to open the .jnlp files on this page http://goworldwind.org/demos/ with both files (I know it sounds stupid) and of course I didn't get anything.

Thank you for read it and I hope you can give me a hand.

Comment: What happens after step 2 isn't normal. You should get a new prompt that looks something like `user@computer-name:/path/to/worldwind$ `

Comment: thank you for answering my question @stonedsquirrel then what's that symbol: > ? I type "exit" and I don't obtain anything.

Comment: Sorry, that one I don't know. You could try `Ctrl` + `C`

Comment: Which command do you use exactly that leads you to this?

Comment: yeah @stonedsquirrel I use: cd "/..." (that it: World Wind folder, self-made creation, not computer automatic creation, if it matters) and with quotation marks inclusive, because of the spaces.

Comment: That's strange. Sorry, still can't help you.

Comment: "cd to the World Wind release folder." you are taking this literally? If so ...don't... they expect you to "cd" to the folder you downloaded the file ;)

Comment: "cd" is the directory command of the terminal @Rinzwind .

Comment: you and @stonedsquirrel thank you both for the help. I solved, now the topic is another one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says you don't have java installed. `type java`  should output something like `java is /usr/bin/java`.  The package you want to install is openjdk-7-jre.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

Then try step 4 again.

On a side-note, if you run `LANG=C` first (without any spaces), the following commands in that terminal will be untranslated (which typically means messages will be in english instead of your selected language).